# Problem with op amp output hitting bottom rail on output stage for DIY 3D printed strain gauge. High gain is needed

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential, gain, strain-gage

So the goal is to take our differential input from our experimental full bridge strain gauge and amplify the signal to a gain of roughly 5500. The output signal would then be going into a 12-bit ADC and information brought in through Arduino SPI.

I've added an image of our circuit here. The left circuit is the strain gauge.

Also Strain gauge PN :SGD-1.5/120-LY13. The strain gauges are not perfectly mounted. They're mounted on 3D printed beams.

[image]

The main problem I've been having for awhile is as we push our gain up high our output signal creeps further and further towards our negative rail. As of now it is sitting at -12V when our strain gauge is in a none activated state.

I believe the main problem is the input voltage of Vo- and Vo+ when the strain gauge is not activated by any forces.

Vo- is around 0.7560V and Vo+ is around 0.7530V.

One thing we had tried is to add a potentiometer to pin 5 (REF) putting pin1 to +12V, pin2 to REF, pin3 to -12V but you had a very high positive offset it would almost be like having a smaller gain. **Is there a way to just inject 30mV into Vo+ to have it the differential voltages equal each other?**

I would appreciate any help, I've wasted a bit too much time testing out different fixes.

Comment: We're using Omega - SGD-1.5/120-LY13

Answer (score 1):

In short, in order to choose max gain, all 4 gauge resistances must be balanced or even better all exactly equal to null gain AND offset error. But for now you just want to correct offset error

i.e.    balanced null offset.

top Left=top right.
bot left = bot right

Then differential error =0 but with some common mode voltage near 0 , if top=bot., but does not affect output offset.

**You can use 15kOhm pullup on the low Vin+ side to 1,5V or add about 1 Ohm to  0.8 in series with top right guage with 5 turn 100 ohm trimmer to bring down Vin-  by the same 3mV.**

But you cannot fix your sensor offset with the REF . that is just for INA offset, which is much less. **Sensor offset would change with gain and you don’t want that.**

### Your error

REF pin is a 60k internal R that controls gain as well with external R by adding large R to offset also reduces output gain.

The problem is your 4leg bridge does not use ground rather it tries to balance the common-mode voltage between V+ and V- supply thus you got ~0.7V. But worse the top parts don’t match nor the bottom or at least the ratio of top to bottom is not balanced.

The offset is at your input before gain so you cannot null it independently on the output using REF.

Since each gage is 120 ohms and your offset is -0.003V you can use your + or - V supply to inject an offset of using 12V/3mV (4k ratio) x 120 ohms = 480Mohm from 12V to Vin+. Which is roughly two 1Gohm resistors in parallel. But this is rather hard to do as dust and humidity could create this offset. The easier way is to make two dividers with lower impedance but then this compromises your CMRR in case you have CM noise nearby, this is also important. If no noise, then you can compromise the excellent CMRR of the INA and try to null the offset without compromising the CM balance and possibly improve it by comparing pull up on Vin+ to pulling down on Vin- for noise rejection.

Normally quad strain gauges are laser trimmed. Yours aren’t and are dependent on mounting balance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A strain gauge is just a wheatstone bridge and those can be adjusted by adding more resistance in the direction (preferably with an adjustable resistance)
One problem with the pullup or pull down is it can contribute to error if you are calculating resistance so if your bridge (I can't tell if all, one or two sides of your bridge resistors are strain gauges). This method works best if you have fixed resistors in the bridge.

With two 120Ω resistors to move the center by 30mV you'd need roughly 6k of resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTTfbW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Another (better) way to do this would be to use pin 5 (reference pin) of the ina118 and a potentiometer to adjust the offset of the INA118

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLaYVs.png)</sup>

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

Comment: Thank you for the comment. All the resistors in the Wheatstone bridge are strain gauges. 

I had tried moving the reference using a pot before with the resistors on the top and bottom though. We had to give the system +12V on the reference pin but the issue that had come up was it seemed like the gain was lowered significantly. I will try both methods again though.

Comment: I would reccomend the bottom method

Comment: The bottom method will not work as the offset is not in the INA but rather the sensors are unbalanced, so this will not work as it affects gain as well. -1  Use method 1 .

Comment: Except for the rails on the instrumentation amp are much wider than the sensor and the ADC so an offset would work at the reference. Also if calculating R using method 1 will create small amounts of error.